# How to append to a segment of the Firebase realtime database using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

As a summer project, I'm making an iOS quiz app that has predetermined users. However, the amount of quizzes and users will change; therefore, I want to take my realtime database that looks like this:

[image: initial database]

and make it so that for every quiz a quiz branch is created and for every student a students branch is created underneath that quiz branch as shown below:

[image: appended database]

Even though my experience with both firebase and Xcode is limited, I know how to read from the database and set a branch to a specific value. Thus the core of the question is how to make new branches or append old branches of a firebase realtime database from Xcode

Xcode ViewController segment below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var greetingLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var students = [Student]()
var quizzes = [Quiz]()
var squizzes = [SpecQuiz]()
var passsedQuizzes = [SpecQuiz]()
var loggedStud = Student(nme: "", id: "")
var count = 0
//variables that are not used are used in different functions not shown for readability

var ref = Database.database().reference()
var refStudents: DatabaseReference!
var refQuizzes: DatabaseReference!   

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    refStudents = Database.database().reference().child("Students")
    refStudents.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.students.removeAll()
            for student in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                let studentObject = student.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let studentName = studentObject?["Name"]
                let studentID = studentObject?["ID"]

                let stud = Student(nme: (studentName as! String?)!, id: (studentID as! String?)!)

//Student is a class that has a name and id attribute

                self.students.append(stud)
            }
        }
    })
    refQuizzes = Database.database().reference().child("Quizzes")
    refQuizzes.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.quizzes.removeAll()
            for quiz in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                let QuizObject = quiz.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let QuizName = QuizObject?["Name"]
                let QuizAvailable = QuizObject?["Available"]

                let quiz = Quiz(nme: (QuizName as! String?)!, id: (QuizAvailable as! Bool?)!)

//Quiz is a class that has a name and available attribute

                self.quizzes.append(quiz)
            }
        }
    })
    for quiz in quizzes{
        //make new quiz branch
        for student in students{
            //make new student branch
        }
    }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Check the link on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the comment, which aspect do you think I'm lacking. IMO the completeness might not be fully addressed but I want to protect the identity of the users that are actually in Xcode and firebase, thus I made an example database to emulate what I would like to do.

Comment: My comment was not for your database but for the fact that you haven't shown your effort... What have you tried so far? Edit your question and post your code. I would also need some clarification around "can autonomously adds new quizzes and new or old students", specifically what do you mean by autonomously?

Comment: sorry if there was any confusion, by autonomously I was referring to a set of nested for loops that would loop whenever there is a quiz make quiz branch and  and another for loop that for every student make a student branch with the score and taken attribute. I'm working on adding my code, but to be brutally honest after seeing what set value did to my initial database (override everything) I haven't tried anything else.

Comment: ok show your attempt so far and we will take it from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a mutable copy of the data, append your new data, then push those changes to Firebase.

### Obj-C example:

```
[[[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"Some_Root"] child:@"Some_Child"] setValue:SOME_DICTIONARY];
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you elaborate how to "push those changes on to Firebase" as in if there is a command to add branches and sub-branches or directly  import a list that has the "mutable copy of the data"

Comment: With Firebase, you simply create an NSArray or NSDictionary and Firebase API has a method to push that data: `child:setValue:`